# SQLite: extended field description

Tags: sqlite

In MS-SQL a field can have a description:

> Name: FName
>
> Description: First Name

Can a SqLite - table have the same??

Thank you!
Reinhard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think SQLite support that.

An *alternative* way is to use comments in the create statement, like this

```
create table foo (
  id integer -- field 1
, name text -- field 2
)
```

then you can get back the create query and see the descriptions.

Example:

```
select sql from sqlite_master where name = 'foo'
```

output:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id integer -- field 1
, name text -- field 2
)
```

Comment: Thank you,
not an ideal way, but manageable, given that small "restriction" of Sqlite.

Comment: Neat trick. I hope I remember that the next time I want to do something like that.